# PHP DateTime 2 hours ahead of current time

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to grab the current time using the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$curDate = new DateTime();
echo $curDate;
```

And the time that it is echoing is 2 hours ahead of Chicago's timezone. Why would this be? My server is set to Chicago's timezone as well.

Comment: its weird that this works, you're echoing an object

Comment: What do you get if you do: `$curDate = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $curDate;` and `$curDate = new DateTime(); $curDate->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $curDate;` ?

Comment: @ghost DateTime implements its own `__toString()` method.

Comment: Can you run `date` from a bash shell on your server? Maybe the time is set wrong

Comment: @JohnConde Which version of `DateTime` implements `__toString()`? I have 5.5.16 and it's not there ~ *"PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"*

Comment: @Phil I just assumed it did if this was working for the OP. After a little research it appears that it does not. So their example should not work as is.

Comment: Voting to close. I feel like OP has abandoned this question

Answer (score 2):

Try this (add date format)....

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$curDate = new DateTime();
echo date_format($curDate,'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: If you have an object, I'd call a method of it: `$curDate->format(...)`

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.2+

```
$datetime = new \DateTime("now",new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$datetime->modify('+2 hour');
```

^^ misunderstanding, thought you needed to adjust by 2 hours, leaving because it's cool.

Best practice is storing dates as UTC either implicitly as a Unix Epoch integer (epoch are always UTC) or ISO8601 which includes timezone in the string. Your servers timezone shouldn't interfere with your codes ability to display the correct time.

Then when you go to use the stored date.

```
$users_timezone = 'America/Chicago';
$datetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$epoch_from_server);
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone($users_timezone);
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
$datetime = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will allow the user to set their timezone in their user profile provided by your code. Another option would be using the timezone that browser reports but these are unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

1) set the timezone of your server properly

```
cd /etc
rm -f localtime
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago localtime
```

2) sync the time with ntp server:

```
yum install ntp ntpdate ntp-doc
chkconfig ntpd on
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

3) set the timezone inside php.ini

```
timezone = "America/Chicago"
```

hope that help.